# Question on indefinite integrals

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to integrate:

$$I_2 = \int \frac{e^{2x} - e^{x} + 1}{(e^x\cos(x) - \sin(x))\cdot \left(e^x\sin(x) + \cos(x)\right)} \text{d}x$$

I simply can't understand from where to begin with. Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Quite unclear.. the integral you want to compute is

$$\int \frac{e^{2x} - e^{x} + 1}{e^x\cos(x) - \sin(x)}\cdot \left(e^x\sin(x) + \cos(x)\right) \text{d}x$$

??

Comment: @Kim Peek II yes you are right  ....

Comment: I don't know the format which you guys are using...

Comment: When you create a question, If you read the information which the website give you, you will get instructions on how you write so that the mathematics looks nice. This lack of formating and the lack of own work (How would you start here? Have you shortened the expressions?) in the question is probably why you have gotten downvotes.

Comment: Seeing your EDIT, it seems it's not the integral I wrote below..

Comment: @ADITYA  So what is the correct one?

Comment: @Kim Peek II your edit is correct ...

Comment: @Ove Ahlman I have tried all ways which is within my potential but I have failed that's why I have asked the question on this platform so that I will get a answer...

Comment: If you have tried many ways, then you should display this. Not just state that you have tried everything. This way we may explain what you have done wrong in your thinking or just state that you should continue your calculations.

Comment: @KimPeekII Thanks for help ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I consulted [Moor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30/moor-xu) and he suggested an approach involving differentiating the denominator.
Let $f(x) = (e^x \cos (x) - \sin(x))$ and $g(x) = (e^x \sin x + \cos x)$.  Then, note that, by the product rule $(fg)'=f'g +g'f = (e^x\cos(x)-e^x\sin(x) - \cos(x))(e^x \sin (x) + \cos (x)) + (e^x\sin (x) + e^x \cos(x)-\sin(x))(e^x \cos(x) - \sin(x))$

but this doesn't cancel out nicely to get $e^{2x}-e^x+1$.  In fact, expanding gives
$$(fg)' = (e^{2x} \sin(x) \cos(x) + e^x \cos^2(x) - e^{2x} \sin^2 (x) - \cos^2(x) - 2e^x \sin(x)\cos(x)) \\
+(e^{2x}\sin(x)\cos(x) - e^x \sin^2(x) + e^{2x} \cos^2 (x) + \sin^2(x) - 2e^x \sin (x) \cos (x))$$
Note that $fg'$ will cancel with a lot of $f'g$ terms if $fg'$ is negative.  In particular, note that $f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x) = -(e^{2x} - e^x + 1)$.

So, our integral looks like

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{e^{2x} - e^{x} + 1}{(e^x\cos(x) - \sin(x))\cdot \left(e^x\sin(x) + \cos(x)\right)} \, dx &=
-\int \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{f(x)g(x)}\,dx \\
&= - \int \left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} - \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} \right) \,dx \\
&= - \ln(f(x)) + \ln(g(x)) + C \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right) + C \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{e^x \sin(x) + \cos(x)}{e^x \cos(x) - \sin(x)} \right) +C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$\int\space\frac{e^{2x}-e^x+1}{\left(e^x\cos(x)-\sin(x)\right)\left(e^x\sin(x)+\cos(x)\right)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$2\int\space\frac{-e^x+e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}\sin(2x)-\sin(2x)+2e^x\cos(2x)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$2\int\space\frac{2\cosh(x)-1}{2\left(\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)\right)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{2}{2}\int\space\frac{2\cosh(x)-1}{\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\space\frac{2\cosh(x)-1}{\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$2\int\space\frac{2\cosh(x)-\frac{1}{2}}{\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$2\int\space\left(\frac{\cosh(x)}{\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)}-\frac{1}{2\left(\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)\right)}\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$2\int\space\frac{\cosh(x)}{\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)}\space\text{d}x-2\int\frac{1}{2\left(\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)\right)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$2\int\space\frac{\cosh(x)}{\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)}\space\text{d}x-\int\frac{1}{\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\sinh(x)}\space\text{d}x$$

Comment: And now what???

Comment: Can you please it without using the hyperbolic functions...

Comment: This is not the integral written above!

Comment: Kim PeekII I guess you have changed the integral

Comment: @Kim PeekII I guess you have changed the question

Comment: @Kim PeekII PLEASE RE CHANGE THE RIGHT PART OF THE NUMERATOR INTO THE DENOMINATOR...

Comment: YOU told me that what I wrote it was the correct one!

Comment: @Kim PeekII Sorry for the inconvenience caused to you...

Comment: @Kim PeekII PLEASE CHANGE THE QUESTION ACCORDINGLY TO WHAT JAN EERLAND HAS SOLVED..

Comment: @ADITYA you could've done it by yourself.. You can edit your own questions! Done it, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a general method for this types of integrals, but if they will give a simple result, it must more or less be done in the following way:

We note that
$$
D(e^x\cos x-\sin x)=e^x(\cos x-\sin x)-\cos x
$$
and
$$
D(e^x\sin x+\cos x)=e^x(\cos x+\sin x)-\sin x.
$$
Next, our aim will be to do a kind of partial fraction decomposition (it is not a rational function, so it should perhaps be called something different),
$$
\frac{e^{2x}-e^x+1}{(e^x\cos x-\sin x)(e^x\sin x+\cos x)}=\frac{f(x)}{e^x\cos x-\sin x}+\frac{g(x)}{e^x\sin x+\cos x}.
$$
If we are really lucky $f(x)$ will be the derivative of $e^x\cos x-\sin x$ and $g(x)$ will be the derivative of $e^x\sin x+\cos x$. Now, as it happens, this is not exactly true. But almost! I encourage you to write
$$
a\frac{e^x(\cos x-\sin x)-\cos x}{e^x\cos x-\sin x}+b\frac{e^x(\cos x+\sin x)-\sin x}{e^x\sin x+\cos x}
$$
on common denominator, and try to find constants $a$ and $b$ so that it equals the original integrand. With that done, the integration will be simple, since it is of the form $a\phi'(x)/\phi(x)+b\psi'(x)/\psi(x)$ and thus giving logarithms. I leave those details to you. Scroll over below to see the final result.

> One gets $a=-1$ and $b=1$, and thus the final result is $$-\ln|e^x\cos x-\sin x|+\ln|e^x\sin x+\cos x|+C$$

Comment: Thanks bro but it seemed that you already knew the answer............

Comment: As i said in the beginning, I don't know a general method, but that if it gonna be something "simple", it must go like this. I gave here the steps as I did them myself...

Comment: Nice one thanks for help...

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution to your problem
Here it goes:
\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{e^{2 x}-e^{x}+1}{\left(e^{x} \sin x+\cos x\right)\left(e^{x} \cos x-\sin x\right)} dx \\
=& \int \frac{e^{2 x}-e^{x}+1}{\left(e^{2 x}+1\right) \sin \left(x+\tan ^{-1} \frac{1}{e^{x}}\right) \cdot \cos \left(x+\tan ^{-1} \frac{1}{e^{x}}\right)} d x \\
=&2 \int \frac{e^{2 x}-e^{x}+1}{\left(e^{2 x}+1\right) \sin \left(2 x+2 \operatorname{ta}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{e^{x}}\right)\right)} d x \\
=&2 \int \frac{e^{2 x}-e^{x}+1}{\left(e^{2 x}+1\right) \sin \left(2 x+2 \cot ^{-1}\left(e^{x}\right)\right)} dx \\=&\int \operatorname{cosec}t~ dt=\ln \left|\tan \frac{t}{2}\right|+c \end{aligned}

where $t=2 x+2 \cot ^{-1}\left(e^{x}\right)$. Note that

$$\frac{d t}{d x}=2-\frac{2}{1+e^{2 x}} \cdot e^{x}=\frac{2\left(e^{2 x}-e^{x}+1\right)}{e^{2 x}+1}$$

Also, $\frac{t}{2}=x+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{e^{x}}\right)$ so we have $$
\tan \frac{t}{2}=\frac{\tan x+\frac{1}{e^{x}}}{1-\frac{t x}{e^{x}}} =\frac{e^{x} \sin x+\cos x}{e^{x} \cos x-\sin x}$$

Thus the integral is $$ \boxed{\ln \left|\frac{e^{x} \sin x+\cos x}{e^{x} \cos x-\sin x}\right|+c} $$